# Values on PostBack getting lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, postback

I am using MVC3 and classes generetad from EntityFranmework for saving some data into a Database.

The controller

```
// Get
public ActionResult Create(Guid StudentID)
{
    Semester semester = new Semester();

    ViewBag.BranchID = new SelectList(db.Branches, "ID", "Name");
    semester.Student = db.Students.Single(s => s.ID == StudentID);

    return PartialView(semester);
} 

//
// POST: /Semester/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Semester semester)
{
    semester.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    semester.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    semester.CreatedBy = "ddf";


    db.Semesters.AddObject(semester);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");      
}
```

I do get all the result of the student at get Method but all the student data are Lost at the post method.

Help!

Comment: Do you mean that the Semester object passed to the Post method is null or has empty values? If so, I suspect it could be a binding problem, in which case could you share your View HTML?

Answer (score 2):

The object passed to POST action is not the same as object passed to the view in GET action. In your POST action you get `Semester` instance created by MVC using ***only*** parameters Request (query string, post data) - that means Student instance is long gone. You will need to pass student ID to POST action and fill it there.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Guid studentID, Semester semester)
{
    semester.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    semester.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    semester.CreatedBy = "ddf";

    semester.Student = db.Students.Single(s => s.ID == StudentID);

    db.Semesters.AddObject(semester);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");      
}
```